# Adding jpg files to zipfile,ignore existing(dont overwrite it)

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

I wanted to know how to add jpg files to a (existing zip with jpg files) ZIP without overwriting the files already in the ZIP.

Comment: try append mode in zip file after having filtered out the files already in the archive

Comment: have you tried something that we can try to improve/make work?

Comment: i thank you so much man :)

Comment: append mode worked and btw if your interested, my code: https://pastebin.com/nE4fcLfw

Comment: the code is strange: it creates the archive, then appends the same files again. That's not whay I had in mind. so it created 2 entries for the same files then?

Comment: It creates the zip with w mode - if zip does not exist

|||||||||||||||||||| add files from ./screenshots with a mode - if zip exists

Comment: that's nice if you solved it